# window.setInterval jQuery function does not work on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   $('#Notify-Bar').html('a new notification');
}, 5000);
```

Did not work on IE, however works fine on other major web browsers (like Chrome, Firefox, Opera)...

Comment: Just a remark: `window.setInterval` is not a jquery function.

Comment: oh sorry.....I've a few months experience of jQuery...however it not work on IE version of web browsers....

Comment: what versin of IE are you using? i've tested it in IE8 and it works as expected.

Comment: I'm using IE8 version of Windows 7....

Comment: Just tested on IE8 Win7, it works! Does it reports some errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use something like

```
setInterval("myFunc()",5000);

function myFunc()
{
    $('#Notify-Bar').html('a new notification');
}
```

Comment: it's the same of window.setInteval(foo,ms); in your case it's better to use setInterval(myFunc,5000) instead of passing a string ;)

Comment: Try just putting `alert("test");` in `myFunc()` to see if the timer is being fired.  Can you show your HTML?

Comment: @Hazro City: http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/ztDWX/ open this URL in IE, wait 5 seconds and tell me if in the "Result" frame you see "a new notification"

Comment: Yeah...when I tested your code at: http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/ it works...I'll check my original code...thanks