# in IE8 setInterval method not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, setinterval, intervals

When i tried the setInterval method in IE8 its not wokring

```
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function msg()
     {
       alert("hello world ");
       document.writeln("hello world <br>");       
     }
     //setInterval("msg();", 3000);
     //setInterval(msg(), 3000);
     //setInterval(msg, 3000);
     setInterval(function(){msg()}, 3000);
   </script>
</body>
```

when google i got several answers

[window.setInterval jQuery function does not work on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745224/window-setinterval-jquery-function-does-not-work-on-ie8)
[setinterval method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678432/setinterval-method-not-working)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/netfxjscript/thread/ff7447f0-3c18-484b-a037-eaf9f60574a8
but when i tried those things on ie8 its not working

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is working fine in your code. The problem is with what you're doing with it. Executing `document.writeln` is wiping out your document, which includes your JavaScript. To see this in action, just add `<p>foo</p>` somewhere in the body and you'll see that it disappears once `document.writeln` is executed. Remove the `document.writeln` line and you'll see that the `alert` occurs over and over again, as expected.

I believe the JavaScript will continue to run in WebKit browsers even though it's been wiped out, but not in non-WebKit browsers like Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253603/setinterval-not-able-to-run-document-writeln) for some ideas on what to do.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jophine/LQ2Rv/  --  the above code is working fine on chrome and mz only problem with ie8. all other browser will get the alert after 3 second. but in ie8 which will execute only once.       about the writeln will display the contents to a new line. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_writeln.asp)

Comment: Chrome is a WebKit browser, so it doesn't surprise me that the fiddle works as you expect with it. However, I just tested the fiddle in Firefox 17.0.1 and Opera 12.11 (both on Mac OS 10.7.5) and, in both browsers, it only showed the `alert` once. Did you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5253655/237244)? Lastly, I don't think W3Schools is a good resource. Google around for reasons why. I suggest you try [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) instead.